# Post datetime type to database with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a ruby on rails app, where the I have a meeting_time that is stored as a datetime type. I want to post it via an ajax call, but JavaScript seems to only have string or object. Is it possible to convert a string into a datetime in JavaScript before posting?

For example, `meeting_time: "2016-11-02 02:31:00"`
posts as a string, or I have tried `date=new Date()`, but this returns an object.

Thanks!

Comment: Inherently, it will pass as a string in the POST.  You will need to convert it from a string to a datetime on the server-side.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you want to convert your JavaScript Date object into a Ruby datetime object? For anything else you can create a JavaScript Date object this way: `var date = new Date('2016-11-02 02:31:00');` and you can access its value in multiple ways with the methods of the Date object. However, I recommend to use something like moment.js for date operations in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ole with js date object, it creates an object. I need to store the date as  the type: datestring.

Comment: I guess this is impossible to do only at the client side. You need to post it as a string to your server and from there you create the datestring object with Ruby.

Comment: Ideally, you'd `new Date(date_string).toISOString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can only pass strings using Ajax. Which makes sense, because a javascript object isn't going to mean much to Ruby. A pretty common way of doing this is to pass JSON to the server and then most languages (including Ruby) can parse the JSON.

Comment: Thanks -- I posted a new question on how to do this in rails, if you want to give that a shot too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345784/take-a-param-in-controller-convert-string-type-and-save